# ${currentdir} target is not generating file anymore

Tags: nlog

I have recently upgraded my asp.net core project to .net core 2.2 and at same time updated NLog.Web.AspNetCore.

After I did this (maybe coincidence?) I noticed that log files are not being generated.

In my config this is my target:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${currentdir}/Logs/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

After some debugging I realised that if I specified the path explicitly then it would generate log file:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="E:\Project\Logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

I have `throwExceptions="true"` set in config but when a file is not generated no exception is thrown, it just silently doesn't create the file.

To further debug this I created a console project and added nuget NLog.Web.AspNetCore and copied my config.  Now in the console project it works fine and is creating log files in the debug output directory.

Is there any way to debug why the log file isn't being generated with this target in my main project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `${currentdir}` then consider using `${aspnet-appbasepath}` (Or `${basedir}` if not in-process-hosting)

NLog [InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) usually gives very good hints when something is not working as expected.

Please avoid using `throwExceptions="true"` as it is for unit-testing, and not for production environments.

Comment: Thanks.  I used the internal log to debug the issue.  It was trying to write to the IIS directory and didn't have permission